# Line chart on a Listview

Tags: android

I have a ListView and inside some rows from that view I have drawn points in different position. Now I need to connect those points (each one in a different row) with a line. It is like a line chart functionality but inside a ListView.

Any idea how can I do that?

Edited:

I thought about getting the total height of the listview and have a frame layout with the same size on top of the listview and then draw the points on that layout giving the coordinates of the view related to each column. But I don't know if it is possible because I also need to draw the points that are not yet on the screen (when the user scroll the listview)

Comment: `I have drawn points` I suppose you used `canvas.drawPoint()`. Having an array of points, you can use `canvas.drawPoints()`. Or simply use `canvas.drawLine()` to connect each point with the next one.

Comment: I think it is no so simple. The points are ImageView created by the list adapter, so the points are inside rows and I have to draw a line between points in different rows.

Comment: Do it in the adapter, exactly after drawing the points.

Comment: Ok, so I created my ListView with a custom CursorAdapter. How can I draw from there a line between for example, a point inside row 2 and another one inside row 6  using canvas.drawLine()? Thanks

Comment: How do you draw the points?

Comment: They are ImageViews: holder.graphPoint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  when I get a parameter with a certain value from the cursor, I set de visibility true in the row view

Comment: So, in your opinion, how could you get the coordinates of random points inside them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do this at that manner. You can't draw line outside of view bounds. That means that you need to have one view which will contains row 2 and row 6. It's impossible in list view.
If you really want to have list view, you need to calculate points in all rows between 2 and 6 and draw separate lines in each of these rows.

Comment: I thought about getting the total height of the listview and have a frame layout with the same size on top of the listview and then draw the points on that layout giving the coordinates of the view related to each column. But I don't know if it is possible because I also need to draw the points that are not yet on the screen (when the user scroll the listview)